# How to replace a character at a certain index with a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Hi i a have string like this one

`My home is a nice home in Paris but i will go to the home of some one else.`

i want to replace the character i starting from index 5 to index 25 of the string with the charater Z with a regular expression.

so the result should be

`"My home Zs a nZce home Zn Paris but i will go to the home of some one else."`

can you help me please?

i'll use it in java application
i must create a webservice receiving the regular expression,the string,the begining index, the ending index and it must return the modifed string.

Thank you verry much.

Comment: What language/regex flavor?

Comment: Please specify the programming language to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
(?<=^.{5,25})i
```

This will match "i", if there are at least 5 and max 25 characters before from the start of the row.

`(?<=^.{5,25})` is a [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), that checks for this condition.

`^` Is an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) that matches the start of the string

```
String s = "My home is a nice home in Paris but i will go to the home of some one else.";
String res = s.replaceAll("(?<=^.{5,25})i", "Z");
```

Output:

> My home Zs a nZce home Zn Paris but i will go to the home of some one else.

Comment: Sorry, but when I started mine, yours was different and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Use [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)

```
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(input);
int index=-1;
while((index=sb.indexOf("i"))!=-1)
{
    if(index>=5&&index<=25)sb.setCharAt(index,'Z')
}
```

---

You could use this **regex** to replace `i` with `Z`

```
(?<=^.{4,25})i
```

So,your code would be

```
input.replaceAll(aboveRegex,"Z")
```

Comment: +1 Very well explained but this regex thing is bit complex and weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way(without regex):-

```
$str= "My home is a nice home in Paris but i will go to the home of some one else";
   for($i=5; $i<25; $i++) 
   if($str[$i]=='i')
         $str[$i] = 'Z';

         echo $str;
```

Output:-

My home Zs a nZce home Zn Paris but i will go to the home of some one else

Comment: [Regex please](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/101/781/Y0UJC.png)

Comment: i know i can do it without regular expression but i don't have the choice

Comment: @user2441352 you don't need to use regex here..keep it simple..but if you still need it check out my ans

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript

```
var str = 'My home is a nice home in Paris but i will go to the home of some one else.';

var result = str.replace(str.substring(5, 25), function (match) {
    return match.replace(/i/g, 'Z');
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: [Regex please](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/101/781/Y0UJC.png)